# Openlayers Leaflet and popup

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, popup

I am working on a map mixing OpenLayers and leaflet libraries (it is possible, correct  ?). 
I am such a beginner that, after lots of readings, I thought creating pop ups was less difficult for me with leaflet than OpenLayers.

After hours spent to display pop ups, I can't find the right manner. I get a

```
TypeError:a.div is undefined
```

HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OpenLayers Example</title>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="./leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="./highlight.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
</head>

 <body>
  <center><div style="width:80%;  height:98%" id="map"></div><center>
  <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        projection: "EPSG:3857", 
        });
    var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

    map.addLayer(osm);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(131046.64, 5990608.29), 9);
    <!--map.zoomTo(9)-->

    //style pour les operations  
    var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        'display': "none", //pas d'affichage de la couche
        'pointRadius': 4,
        'strokeColor': "red",
        'strokeWidth': 0.5
    });

    var selectStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        'pointRadius': 10
    });

    var operationStyle = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'default': defaultStyle,
                            'select': selectStyle});

   //layer communes d'apres geojson
    var commune = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
        "commune", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "communes.geojson",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        //autre maniere de creer un style
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            'fillOpacity': 0,
            'strokeColor': "red",
            'strokeWidth': 0.8,
            'label': "${nom_comm}",
            'fontFamily': "Verdana",
            'fontWeight': "bold",
            'fontSize': "7px",
            'labelOutlineColor': "white",
            'labelOutlineWidth': 1
        })
        }
    );
  map.addLayer(commune);      

 $.getJSON("emprise.geojson", function(data) {
             var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.gid);
  }
});
 geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
 });      
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why are you using both libraries, you should choose one - Leaflet or OpenLayers and work with that one. This code isn't working because you didn't defined Leaflet map:

```
map = L.map('map');
```

You defined OpenLayers map as map and in this line

```
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

you're adding leaflet layer to leaflet map (map) but it can't find L.map defined.

So, the best thing is to use only one library to avoid this kind of conflicts.

Comment: I agree with againstflow, you can't have a map that will react with openlayers and leaflet functions in the same time.

Comment: like i said at the start : i wanted to use the "best" of each librairies (i.e. th easiest or what it seems to be for me). And I thought that mix the two librairies was possible. Work on progress so...